# Electron Builde errror on GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, electron-builder

On GitLab CI the electron build fails with: **`x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`**

Since we have set the env-var `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` to  `true`, this should not happen, right? [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/tls-self-signed.html)

Any idea how to fix this?

Relevant log output:

```
$ export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
..
> nx run dmc-el:make 
*********************************************************
DO NOT FORGET TO REBUILD YOUR FRONTEND & BACKEND PROJECTS
FOR PRODUCTION BEFORE PACKAGING / MAKING YOUR ARTIFACT!
*********************************************************
  • electron-builder  version=22.14.13 os=5.4.109+
  • skipped dependencies rebuild  reason=npmRebuild is set to false
  • packaging       platform=linux arch=x64 electron=18.3.4 appOutDir=dist/apps/dmc-executables/linux-unpacked
  ⨯ Get "https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v18.3.4/electron-v18.3.4-linux-x64.zip": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).follow.func1
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:206
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).follow
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:234
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).DownloadNoRetry
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:128
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/download.(*Downloader).Download
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/download/downloader.go:112
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.(*ElectronDownloader).doDownload
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:192
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.(*ElectronDownloader).Download
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:177
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/electron.downloadElectron.func1.1
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/electron/electronDownloader.go:73
github.com/develar/app-builder/pkg/util.MapAsyncConcurrency.func2
    /Volumes/data/Documents/app-builder/pkg/util/async.go:68
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.16.5/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371  
Error: /builds/daqmon/src/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/builds/daqmon/src/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:250:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

Notes:

- when we execute the same commands in a local docker container (same image as used by GitLab CI), it works

Comment: `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` only has an effect on git's behavior. From the output you've shown it seems you are downloading a file via https. That is not related to git. I would recommend updating the ca certificates in your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not related to git, so `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY` was useless.
The error occurred when electron-builder tried to download some files from GitHub via https.

The solution is to update the CA certficates in the docker-container before executing electron-builder:

```bash
apt-get update && apt-get --yes install ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates
```

I guess that my local docker-container had newer certificates for some reason, than the GitLab CI docker-container.

Thanks [Jonas V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18578075/jonas-v) for the helpful comment!